# Cannot calculate the outer product of matrix?

Tags: matlab

So i have two matrices in Matlab and im trying to produce the outer product of them but failed to locate the function for it.

Comment: Can you explain what you call outer product please?

Comment: If you are refering to the extended outer product for matrices (i.e. kronecker product), you'll find what you need here : http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matrix multiplication in matlab is just `*`. If you want elemntwise you need to add a dot befor `.*`. So:
A*B

Comment: if you want element wise multiplication i.e a_11*b_11, a_12*b_12 and so on you need A.*B if you want the matrix multiplication the A*B. For the former, the second dimension of A needs to match the first dimension of B. for the latter, the matrices' sizes need to be identical